# Adding objects to array in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've tried to add an object to my array savedTemplates in a service with the function getTemplates.
I've used a service for this in order to access the templates in multiple views.
Unfortunately, if i try to call my function, nothing happens.

**services.js:**

```
    .factory('templateData', function(){
  var savedTemplates = [
      {"name":"Adam Müller", "iban":"AT29100020003000","image":"adam.jpg"},
      {"name":"Ben Streicher","iban":"AT34900080007000","image":"ben.png"},
      {"name":"Max Krossmann","iban":"AT23400050006000","image":"max.png"}
  ];

  var getTemplates = function(){
    return savedTemplates;

  };

  var addTemplates = function(insertName,insertIban){
    savedTemplates.push=({"name": insertName, "iban": insertIban, "image": 'mike.png'});
    alert("This is savedTemplates:" + savedTemplates);
  };
  return {
    getTemplates:getTemplates,
    addTemplates:addTemplates
  };
})
```

**template-save.html:**

```
<button  class="button button-large button-positive" ng-click="addTemplates(newreceiver,newiban)" ui-sref="tab.templates">
  Speichern
</button>
```

I would be very grateful for any help, since I'm quite desperated already.

Comment: You need to inject the service in the controller and call the function from there

Comment: Do you mean to call a function click for instance in the controller, which calls the service ( templateData.addTemplates(x,y) ) again? :)

Comment: Yeah, Have "addTemplates" function in the controller that calls templateData.addTemplates(newreceiver,newiban) after injecting the service

Comment: Alright!
If I got your point, i should create a variable like $scope.tempateData=templateData.addTemplates(x,y), then i could use addTemplates(x,y) at the ng-click, right?

Comment: $scope.addTemplates = function(x,y){ templateData.addTemplates(x,y) }.           if you do it your way you should call, tempateData in the ng-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample snippet.

You also have a problem in your factory `addTemplates` code, you should use `savedTemplates.push ({ ... }]`,  not `savedTemplates.push = ({ ... }]`

**Snippet**

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.
module('app')
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'templateData', function($scope, templateData) {
    $scope.addTemplates = templateData.addTemplates;
  }])
  .factory('templateData', function() {
    var savedTemplates = [{
        "name": "Adam Müller",
        "iban": "AT29100020003000",
        "image": "adam.jpg"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ben Streicher",
        "iban": "AT34900080007000",
        "image": "ben.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Max Krossmann",
        "iban": "AT23400050006000",
        "image": "max.png"
      }
    ];

    var getTemplates = function() {
      return savedTemplates;
    };

    var addTemplates = function(insertName, insertIban) {
      savedTemplates.push ({
        "name": insertName,
        "iban": insertIban,
        "image": 'mike.png'
      });
      console.log("This is savedTemplates:" + JSON.stringify(savedTemplates, null, 2));
    };
    return {
      getTemplates: getTemplates,
      addTemplates: addTemplates
    };
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <button ng-click="addTemplates('Marty McFly', 'BTTF900080007000')">
  Speichern
</button>
</body>

</html>
```